# T-SQL conversion failed error message

Tags: t-sql

I am getting the following error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2010-01-10' to data type int.
```

While running the following command in a query window in Management Studio:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT CAST(group_id AS INT) AS qqq from view_jct_snapshot_group_items
) AS X
WHERE qqq = CAST(14290 AS INT)
```

However, when I run just this portion of the query, I get results and no errors:

```
SELECT CAST(group_id AS INT) AS qqq from view_jct_snapshot_group_items
```

Similarly with the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT CAST(group_id AS INT) AS qqq from view_jct_snapshot_group_items
) AS X
```

What is going on, and how can I use my where clause without getting an error?

Comment: Why are you casting `14290` as an `int`???

Comment: Change `WHERE qqq = CAST(14290 AS INT)` to `WHERE qqq = 14290` and see if that works.

Comment: Also, group_id is already an int, right?  I think the problem is more likely in your view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table that is the source data for the view most likely has the value `'2010-01-10'` in the `group_id` column and this is excluded by a filter in the View itself.

Views are inline constructs expanded out by the query optimiser and it looks like your query is pushing the cast down to before the filter occurs.

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT CAST(CASE
                      WHEN group_id NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN group_id
                    END AS INT) AS qqq
        FROM   view_jct_snapshot_group_items) AS X
WHERE  qqq = 14290
```

Comment: This answer seems to be on the right track. Not sure whether I will get a chance to investigate today or if it will need to wait for sometime next week due to scheduling. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(group_id AS INT) AS qqq from view_jct_snapshot_group_items
```

This will need to be able to cast all values in the view to int. Clearly at least one of the values is not an int. Try putting your WHERE clause in the derived table not outside of it.

In general it is bad idea to store data that is not the same datatype in one field. This cause many problems in writing queries and requires you to do a lot of what should be unnecessary work (at a performance cost system wide) to cast the data to the correct type. Personally I would revisit your desing to see why integers and dates are stored in the same field.